# How to print sub-class name in pydantic?

Tags: python, subclass, pydantic, python-dataclasses

I used pydantic to define a class. I created a sub-class inherent from a parent class. When I print sub-class, why does it still show the parent class name? What should I do to print Word class?

```
class SubWord(BaseModel):
    word: str
    label: str

Word = SubWord

word = [Word(word="apple",label="fruit")]
print(f'word: {word}')
```

This is the result:

```
word: [SubWord(word='apple', label='fruit')]
```

But I am expecting:

```
word: [Word(word='apple', label='fruit')]
```

What should I do here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `Word` is nothing, only a variable name, it could be anything and has no meaning, whereas SubWord has a meaning as it's a class name

Comment: Why do you say that `Word class` and `parent class` ? The only class u=is SubWord

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any class and not just Pydantic's would behave in the same way

```
class Asd:
    pass

Lol = Asd
```

```
>>> Asd
__main__.Asd
>>> Lol
__main__.Asd
```

In my example `Lol` is simply a new variable pointing at `Asd`, so it's not a new class.

In your case, if `SubWord` and `Word` are identical there is no need for you to separate them. Just use `Word` if that's the word you want to use in your code.

If you need to separate them for some good reason, then you can use inheritance to effectively copy and rename

```
class Word(SubWord):
    pass
```